# Loading img using rxAndroid

Tags: android, retrofit2, android-glide, rx-android

What is best way to loading images from rest API to recyclerView
request structure:

```
[
  {
    "asset_id": "name",
    "url": "https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/bbxt-static-icons/type-id/png_16/f231d7382689406f9a50dde841418c64.png"
  },

]
```

using glide rxandroid and retrofit.
My @GET

```
 @GET("exchanges/icons/")
    fun getIcons(): Observable<List<IconsCurrency>>
```

what will be the next steps?

Comment: refer this--> https://medium.com/@prakash_pun/retrofit-a-simple-android-tutorial-48437e4e5a23

Answer (score 0):

I used in the past picasso library:
https://square.github.io/picasso/

Why? i found it super easy to use and has also some advantage as written in the first lines of their website:

1. Handling ImageView recycling and download cancelation in an adapter.
2. Complex image transformations with minimal memory use.
3. Automatic memory and disk caching.

   If you need any sample just ask